# Does Michonne ever reveal who her pet walkers were?

Tags: the-walking-dead

So, Michonne's pet walkers: who were they, and where did they come from? Is it ever revealed?

I guess this question would be directed more towards the comic book fans, since the best answer in the show has been "they deserved what they got, they weren't human to begin with". Other that that she always clams up at the subject.

I have my theories, but because she is so reluctant to reveal anything about herself it's really difficult to put any stock in those theories...

Answer (score 21):

**In the comics, the two "pet" walkers are identified as Michonne's boyfriend [Mike](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Mike_%28Comic_Series%29) and his best friend [Terry](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Terry_%28Comic_Series%29).**

As explained in [The Walking Dead Wiki](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Michonne_%28Comic_Series%29):

> In the early stages of the apocalypse, Michonne runs on foot to her house. This attracts a street full of zombies to follow her. While she arrives home, **she meets her boyfriend, Mike and his brave but idiotic best friend, Terry.** A zombie tries to break in but Mike kills it. In the process, Mike becomes bitten. At that time, Michonne bandages Mike, who is unaware that he is infected. That night, Michonne searches a neighbor's house for supplies and discovers her trademark sword. She gets pinned down in the house during the night and returns home the next day, finding that both Mike and Terry have become walkers. She manages to survive their attack and lock them away. Her noisy encounter causes her street to become overrun. Michonne becomes trapped and runs out of food. **She notices walkers don't attack one another and hacks off the arms and lower jaws of Mike and Terry.** She chains them up by their necks to use them as escorts for an escape that was successful. Michonne says her final words to the zombified Mike and Terry, to help remember who they are, and because she has no one to talk to.

---

**In the TV show, the "pet" walkers are again identified as Mike and Terry.** Whether Mike is her boyfriend or husband is a little unclear, but she also had a three year old son named Andre Anthony. At this time, there has been no revelation as to how any of them died. Contrasting the comics, in this version, she turns them into "pets" so that she can keep them with her, and only later realizes that they help ward off other walkers.

Comment: but in s03e14 in the beginning you see Andrea and Michonne in the woods before woodburry and Andrea asks who the walkers are, the only thing that Michonne says is that they got what they deserved. Why would she want her boyfriend to become a walker?

Comment: @Timon, 1) I specified that they were revealed as her boyfriend and his friend *in the comics*. So far, she has not specified their identities in the TV show. Both possibilities are equally possible at this point. 2) Them becoming walkers had nothing to do with her. She would want to keep them with her as long as possible because they were her last link to life before the outbreak. And, as the answer says, she has no one else to talk to at that point.

Comment: @Timon she said that because she was angry at them for getting high, which allowed their camp to be overrun, resulting in them being bitten and her son Andre being killed.